# DataTable returns null WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to display data in a datagrid based on value selected in a ComboBox but my datatable function returns null and nothing is displayed in the datagrid.

```
 public DataTable ReadData(User user)
    {
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(AppConnect.Connection))
        {
            string query = "SELECT moduleCode,moduleName,modCredits,modHrsLeft FROM [Module] WHERE userName=@userName";
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db))
                {
                    if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        db.Open();
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user.UserName);

                        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                        table = new DataTable();
                        dataAdapter.Fill(table);


                    }
                }
                db.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return table;
        }
    }
```

This function is in a class library. The function is called in the WPF project, this is the code:

```
  private void BtnDisplay_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = CmboxUserN.SelectedItem.ToString();
       
        User user1 = new User
        {
            UserName = userName
        };

        DataTable table = data.ReadData(user1);
        gridModules.DataContext= table;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes. It seems that the line `table = new DataTable();` is never being hit. You don't need to check to make sure the connection is in a closed state because you are using a `using` statement.

```
    public DataTable ReadData(User user)
    {
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(AppConnect.Connection))
        {
            string query = "SELECT moduleCode,moduleName,modCredits,modHrsLeft FROM [Module] WHERE userName=@userName";
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, db))
                {
                    db.Open();
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", user.UserName);

                    SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
                    table = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(table);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return table;
        }
    }
```

Also, you don't need to `.Close()` the connection because the `SqlConnection` is in a using statement, which means the object will be disposed of when the scope of the using statement is exited.

One other tip: You should change the code to have the try catch around everyting and if there are any errors at all, log the errors to console and return a `new DataTable()`.

Comment: That would throw a nullreference error @kristech

Comment: Sorry, I  made a mistake in the code you fixed.

Comment: if i answered your question, please mark question as answered. thanks!